# Handle clicks in table view cell

Tags: objective-c, ios

Im new to IOS developing and i would like, as one of my start projects to learn more about table views. I would like to fill a table view up and then be able to handle clicks on them, to open a webpage etc. Does someone know a good tutorial or code for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) documentation.

Specifically, `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. You can then lookup the cell at the given indexPath and handle it accordingly. More info on delegation can be found in the docs if you need it, but you'll want to implement methods like that in the object referenced as the `delegate` of your tableView